# Reasonml syntax meaning |

Tags: reason

What does this symbol mean in ReasonML `|`

E.g

```
type something = 
| SomeFunc()
| AnotherFunc()
```

I couldnt really find an answer on the ReasonML docs

Comment: Its meaning changes depending on context. Here it's just a separator, separating the different cases of the variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, this particular one is a case of defining a custom type.

We are defining a new type called **something**, the values of which can be created using either the function **SomeFunc** or **AnotherFunc**.. More specifically, these functions are called **Constructor Functions**... Quite useful with pattern-matching.

You can read more about them in the [OCaml documentation](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html).

You can also find the pipe symbol (`|`) inside pattern-matching constructs, separating various cases/variations of match-patterns.